# LT-Spice wont open file -> File limitations?

Tags: simulation, ltspice

I am currently working on bulk simulations. For this I created a Python script which writes in the .asc files of LTspice and creates long tables, which are stepped through with the run variable. This is to write predefined simulation runs.

I need to create files which run about 1,000,000 simulations long. After I ran the python script the file was about 2.7GB big. But now LTspice refuses to open it. When I try to open it it loads and after a minute or so it just closes the window without any message or notice. And there isnt even a crash note.

According to LTspice, there should be no file limitations, but I think there actually is one. And my PC cant be the problem, I have 64GB of ram and a 12 core processor (Ryzen 9 3900x).

So how do I solve this?

Comment: File may be too big to be written or read "at once" at T time & have been corrupted by a bad priority of writting  processus (not in good order) this happens rarerely but it happens. You can avoid that kind of issue with git  so you can always go back to a previous version or other branch of your file  whatever happens ...

Comment: LTSpice has data limitations, it can handle e.g. 65536 entries per voltage node/current (see https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/448643/200815). You could try limiting the Python script to 65535 datapoints and check if this is the issue.

Comment: @Huisman While that is true, it does not apply to OP, who can't open the file, so OP can't even simulate.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I think you are not correct. OP writes: *When I try to open it it loads and after a minute or so*  (so  LTSpice **succeeds** to open it) *it just closes the window without any message or notice*. I think LTspice succeeds to open it, but exceeds a data limit and crashes. It might be due to the datapoints limit, but I am not sure. Hence the comment, not an answer.

Comment: Since Python is able to generate the file, I would **think** the OS also supports such large files and would therfore conclude the problem lies within LTspice.

Comment: @Huisman This is the part that made me think this way: *But now LTspice refuses to open it*. The line you quote, which comes next, led me to believe that LTspice doesn't really load the file, as in you click "Open", and then LTspice's window, though still on the screen, tries to handle the file but you can't actually do a thing, it is frozen. Maybe the OP could clarify it a bit?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen: LTspice can open an empty window without any files opened. Normally i could drag&drop the file into that window to open it, but this does not work. If i click on the "open" action and select the 2GB file, it shows the loading circle at the cursor for 1-2 minutes, then the empty window closes without a notice.

Comment: @Huisman: i dont know why datapoints might be an issue since i am only creating long tables and nothing else. And if datapoints are the problem, the file should open and fail when i try to simulate.

Comment: @jonspice2 Please follow the help center directions for how to merge your two accounts: electronics.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: "the **2GB** file" - what happens if the file is smaller than 2GB?

Comment: So: if the file is 2GB it wont open. This continues on till the file is about 150MB big, then it opens.

Comment: Could you tell what tables you're trying to load?

Comment: @Huisman what do you mean with „what tables?“. I think there is only one kind of table. But if you want a layout of a table, ill provide one here: .param R868_bit table (run, 1, 0.788, 2, 0.988, 3, -0.882, ...)

Comment: And i have to add: the graphical view of the circuit is really laggy at 150MB filesize. Also the view contains the long tables underneath the circuit, which is hard to see since it zooms out quite a bit (to show the tables completely). Zooming in is really slow and laggy. Could it be that the graphics are too much for LTspice?

Comment: @jonspice you can solve the unreadable circuit by turning the comment invisible (either by right-mouse-click or using **Invisible** in  ```TEXT xxx yyy Invisible 2 !.param R868_bit …```

Comment: @Huisman this works only if you are doing it manually and only until you reopen the file. Then the directions appear somewhere further down and a bit scrambled. Maybe its just a temporary state which you cannot recreate?